# Triggering onClick jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following bit of code:

```
<a id="content4" class="navlink switcher" style="color:#002EB8" onclick="function(){$('#slider').nivoSlider();}" name="content4">Photos</a>
```

However, it doesn't work. How do I modify it/place a new script in the `<head>` to make the function execute properly?

Comment: Either you hit your cap locks key by accident or you're stuck in the 90's.

Comment: I didn't write this, my friend did. I'm just helping him figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: But you're not really, are you? You're just posting it here for us to figure out, and you're not handing out any details. What is `nivoSlider`? What does it do? What happens when you run it? Any errors?

Comment: And for someone who's helping out a friend, all your questions on SO are about this "nivo" library.

Comment: @Xeon06. Probably a very close friend... Nice catch!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `inline code`, attach the click event the handler this way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#content4').click(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want omething like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/andreapier/P6Qxs/)?
It is not very clear, next time try to be more specific!